# Copying all text to a new tab or buffer in vim

Tags: vim

I have this function which get all text of current tab and does an echo on it.

```
function! Copy2new ()
   let alltext = getline(1,'$')  
   for s in alltext
      echo s
   endfor
endfunction
```

I know that `:tabnew` can create a new tab. How can I use above function to put entire text of one buffer to a new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Copies current buffer into a new buffer in a new tab**

```
function! Copy2new()
   let alltext = getline(1,'$')  
   tabnew
   call setline('.', alltext)
endfunction
```